# Combining Dwolla's guestSend and registerUser?

Tags: payment, dwolla

If I combine guestSend and registerUser into a single `<form>`, will that user's bank account be immediately verified after that?

Would this prevent me from having to call `verifyFundingSource()`, i.e., 3-5 days waiting for Dwolla to sync up with the bank?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Guest Send feature will not verify a bank account for a Dwolla user.  You'll always need to wait for Dwolla to verify a new funding source for an account - there's no way to bypass that, unfortunately.